# using .loc to query not null values and string only values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to query a dataframe to remove all nulls and numeric (int, float) values.

My Dataframe:

```
make_df = ["Hello", "World", "abcd", 12.4, np.nan,  "qwerty123"]
df = pd.DataFrame(make_df, columns = ["col1"])
```

My Code:

```
df.loc[df["col1"].isna() == False]
```

So far, all I can do is to remove the null values in the DataFrame but not the numeric values.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` with test not missing values chained with testing not missing values:

```
df1 = df[pd.to_numeric(df["col1"], errors='coerce').isna() & df["col1"].notna()]
```

Or is possible test by `isinstance` if need distinguish between string representation of numeric and numeric values:

```
df1 = df[~df['col1'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (float, int)))]
```

---

```
print (df1)
        col1
0      Hello
1      World
2       abcd
5  qwerty123
```

Check difference in solutions - `10` is string repr of numeric:

```
make_df = ["Hello", "World", "abcd", 12.4, np.nan,  "qwerty123", "10"]
df = pd.DataFrame(make_df, columns = ["col1"])
print (df)
        col1
0      Hello
1      World
2       abcd
3       12.4
4        NaN
5  qwerty123
6         10

df1 = df[pd.to_numeric(df["col1"], errors='coerce').isna() & df["col1"].notna()]
print (df1)
        col1
0      Hello
1      World
2       abcd
5  qwerty123

df2 = df[~df['col1'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (float, int)))]
print (df2)
        col1
0      Hello
1      World
2       abcd
5  qwerty123
6         10
```

Comment: Oh..that's why "isinstance" isn't working..may I know why is there a "~" in the dataframe?

Comment: @Maku - It is for inverse boolean mask - `True, False` to `False, True` mask

Comment: Note: `type(np.nan)` is `float`, so I don't think that `notna()` is required here.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be fill the `NaN` with `0` and filter out the numerics using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.col1.fillna(0),errors='coerce').isna(),'col1']
```

---

```
0        Hello
1        World
2         abcd
5    qwerty123
Name: col1, dtype: object
```